# If I add the same product twice from a text file how do I output it one one line with the product price added together?

Tags: c#

I am making a Cash Register basically that reads products from a text file so it can be added during the runtime and in my code so far if I add e.g "Bananas * 1" and then again add "Bananas * 1" it shows up on different lines. What I want to do is if I add Bananas a second time to display only "Bananas * 2".

I have tried checking if my list contains product ID already and if so to check if the product amount is not 0 to add "ProductAmount += ProductAmount" but none of it seems to work.

```
public static void ProduceInfo()
{
  ProdFromText();
  string input = "";
  bool keepGoing = true;
  while ( keepGoing )
  {
    Console.Write("\n<ProductID>  <Quantity>\n");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();

    while ( answer != "pay" )
    {
      var data = answer.Split(' ');
      var data1 = int.Parse(data[0]);
      var data2 = int.Parse(data[1]);

      foreach ( var item in Products )
      {
        if ( item.ProductID == data1 )
        {
          item.TotalPrice = item.ProductPrice * data2;
          if ( item.ProductID == data1 )
          {
            input = String.Format("{0} {1:C} * {2}{3:C}  =   {4:C}", 
                                  item.ProductName, 
                                  item.ProductPrice, 
                                  data2, 
                                  item.ProductType, 
                                  item.TotalPrice);
            Purchase.grandTotal += item.TotalPrice;
          }
        }
      }
      finalProducts.Add(input);
      Console.Clear();
      Purchase.TextToScreen();
      return;
    }
    if ( answer == "pay" )
    {
      //ReceiptNo++;
      //ReceiptHandler();
      Purchase.TextTofile();
      keepGoing = false;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```
public static void ProdFromText()
{
  var readers = "..\\..\\Products.txt";
  List<string> line = File.ReadAllLines(readers).ToList();
  foreach ( var reads in line )
  {
    string[] productSplit = reads.Split(' ');

    Produces newProduct = new Produces();

    newProduct.ProductName = productSplit[0];
    newProduct.ProductPrice = Double.Parse(productSplit[1]);
    newProduct.ProductType = productSplit[2];
    newProduct.ProductID = Int32.Parse(productSplit[3]);

    Products.Add(newProduct);
  }
}
```

```
public static void TextToScreen()
{
  var dateReceipt = DateTime.Now;

  Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\t\t***CASH REGISTER***");
  Console.WriteLine("\nREGISTER");
  Console.WriteLine("-RECEIPT  " + dateReceipt);
  Console.WriteLine("Item   Price  Quantity   Total\n\n");
  TheProducts();
  Console.WriteLine("\nTOTAL:                 {0:C}", grandTotal);
  Produces.ProduceInfo();

  return;
}
```

My expectation is to have output on one line with the amount of products added together and also the total amount added from that. So far I can only get them on separate lines although adding the total amount seems to work fine, even though my grandTotal is currently adding the last added product twice to my grand total price.

**SOLVED USING IDICTIONARY**

```
public static IDictionary<int, Produces> TheDictionary { get; private set; }

    public static void ProdInCart()
            {
                TheDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Produces>();
                v

ar readerNew = "..\\..\\Products.txt";
            List<string> lineNew = File.ReadAllLines(readerNew).ToList();
            foreach (var reads in lineNew)
            {
                string[] productSplitCart = reads.Split(' ');

                Produces cartProducts = new Produces();

                cartProducts.ProductName = productSplitCart[0];
                cartProducts.ProductPrice = Double.Parse(productSplitCart[1]);
                cartProducts.ProductType = productSplitCart[2];
                cartProducts.ProductID = Int32.Parse(productSplitCart[3]);
                cartProducts.maxProductAllowed = Int32.Parse(productSplitCart[4]);

                TheDictionary.Add(cartProducts.ProductID, cartProducts);
            }
        }
```

```
public static void addItem(int id, int amount)
            {
                if (ProductCart.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    ProductCart[id] += amount;
                }
                else
                {
                    ProductCart.Add(id, amount);
                }
            }
```

addItem(Product.ProductID, data2); sends my key and amount in and my addItem method does the rest.

Comment: `finalProducts.Add(input);` This will add another bananas line to the list. You can first check if `finalProducts` has a banana line and if it does, replace that. In your post you say you tried that - maybe post that code so we can see what went wrong. Or you can use a `Dictionary<string, int>` or maybe `Dictionary<Produces, int>`.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out exactly how to replace my banana line with a banana line containing the new amount of bananas. But using a `if(data2 != 0)` seems to work, at least to check if data2 (which is the amount of a product) is already entered for said product.

Comment: I also tried doing `if (finalProducts.Contains(item.ProductID.ToString())) {data2 += data2; }` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search the list to see if there is already a product with that name and if there is, increment:

```
void AddToList(string name, int count)
{
    // Go through entire list
    for (var i = 0; i < finalProducts.Count; i++) {
        var s = finalProducts[i];
        // Search for product name
        if (s.StartsWith(name)) {
           // TODO: put in try/catch
           // Get name and current count
           var parts = s.Split(new[] { " * " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
           // Increment
           var newCount = Int32.Parse(parts[1]) + count;
           // Update list
           finalProducts[i] = String.Format("{0} * {1}", name, newCount);
           return;
        }
    }
    // If we are here, it was not previously in list
    finalProducts.Add(String.Format("{0} * {1}", name, count));
}
```

Another option is to use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> finalProducts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then adding becomes simpler:

```
void AddToList(string name, int count)
{
    // In the list already?
    if (finalProducts.ContainsKey(name)) {
        finalProducts[name] += count;
    }
    // No? Add it
    else {
        finalProducts[name] = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing. thank you so much, this works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Cart` class and a `CartItem` class to represent the `Product`s that the customer is purchasing. I think this has several advantages over the approach you're using now...

1. The `Product` and the `Quantity` being purchased are coupled together in the `CartItem` class, rather than being stored in the `Product` class and a `string` that you're parsing.
2. The total amount being paid per `Product` can be calculated from the `CartItem` class, rather than storing it on the `Product` class. Storing it on the `Product` class means you have to reload the products for each customer, like you're doing now, otherwise the 'TotalPrice' is going to keep increasing for each customer.
3. You can encapsulate the logic for adding a `Product` and increasing the `Quantity` to the `Cart` class.
4. I just think it's much easier to reason about and follow than using raw strings like you're doing now.

So, if you added these classes it might look something like...

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CashRegister
{
   public class Product
   {
      public int ProductId { get; set; }
      public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
      public string ProductType { get; set; }
      public string ProductName { get; set; }

      // Rather than reading from a text file, I've just created this static method to return a few products
      // so I can do some testing.
      public static Product[] GetProducts()
      {
         return new Product[]
         {
            new Product
            {
               ProductId = 1,
               ProductPrice = 1.75d,
               ProductType = "Produce",
               ProductName = "Banana"
            },
            new Product
            {
               ProductId = 2,
               ProductPrice = 0.75d,
               ProductType = "Produce",
               ProductName = "Apple"
            },
            new Product
            {
               ProductId = 3,
               ProductPrice = 59.99,
               ProductType = "Electronics",
               ProductName = "Video Game"
            },
            new Product
            {
               ProductId = 4,
               ProductPrice = 39.99,
               ProductType = "Health",
               ProductName = "Aspirin"
            },
         };
      }
   }

   public class CartItem
   {
      public CartItem(Product product)
      {
         _product = product;
      }

      // I've exposed the properties of the Product class in this fashion, rather than exposing the Product itself
      // so that the Product cannot be modified through the CartItem. 
      public int ProductId => _product.ProductId;
      public double ProductPrice => _product.ProductPrice;
      public string ProductType => _product.ProductType;
      public string ProductName => _product.ProductName;
      public int Quantity { get; set; }

      // Here, we know the quantity and we know the product's price, so we can calculate the total price being
      // paid.
      public double TotalPrice => ProductPrice * Quantity;

      public override string ToString() =>
         string.Format("{0,-13}{1,-8:C}{2,-11}{3:C}", ProductName, ProductPrice, Quantity, TotalPrice);

      private readonly Product _product;
   }

   public class Cart
   {
      public void Add(Product product, int quantity)
      {
         // Look for an item in the cart for the given product.
         var item = _items.SingleOrDefault(ci => ci.ProductId == product.ProductId);
         if (item == null)
         {
            // If the given product is not already in the cart, create a new CartItem for that Product, and add
            // it to the cart.
            item = new CartItem(product);
            _items.Add(item);
         }
         // Increase the quantity being purchased.
         item.Quantity += quantity;
      }

      public void Print()
      {
         Console.WriteLine(" *** Customer Cart ***");
         Console.WriteLine("Item         Price   Quantity   Total");
         foreach (var item in _items)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
         }
         Console.WriteLine("Total:                          {0:C}", Total);
      }

      // We can calculate the grand total based on the items in the cart.
      public double Total => _items.Sum(ci => ci.TotalPrice);

      private readonly List<CartItem> _items = new List<CartItem>();
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var products = Product.GetProducts();
         var cart = new Cart();
         var keepGoing = true;
         while (keepGoing)
         {
            cart.Print();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("<ItemId> <Quantity>");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if ("pay" != answer)
            {
               // There are several checks we should be doing, such as whether the "answer" is in the format
               // we expect and whether there is a Product with the given id.
               // But for the purposes of this example, we'll just assume everything is correct.
               var data = answer.Split(' ');
               var productId = int.Parse(data[0]);
               var quantity = int.Parse(data[1]);

               Product product = products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == productId);
               cart.Add(product, quantity);
               Console.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
               keepGoing = false;
            }
         }

      }
   }
}
```